# Doesn't creating "a currentUser type property on a User struct" lead to infinite recursion?

Tags: swift, data-structures

Learning Swift programming with "App development with Swift" from Apple.
I've faced a difficulty with the following task in Chapter 2.3:

> Imagine you have an app that requires the user to log in. You may have
>   a `User` struct similar to that shown below. However, in addition to
>   keeping track of specific user information, you might want to have a
>   way of knowing who the current logged in user is. Create a `currentUser`
>   type property on the `User` struct below and assign it to a user object
>   representing you. Now you can access the current user through the `User`
>   struct. Print out the properties of `currentUser`.
>
> ```
> struct User {
>
>     var userName: String
>
>     var email: String
>
>     var age: Int
>
> }
> ```

If I understood correctly, I need to create `currentUser` property of type `User` within the `User` struct? This will lead to an infinite recursion, won't it? Hence, I'm not sure that I got this correct. Please help to clarify.

Comment: BTW - did you actually try adding the type property before posting this question? If not, why not? If so, what happened?

Comment: Yep, I've added, but the problem is that I was not attentive enough and missed that type properties should be with the value already. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Read the exercise carefully. It's asking you to create a [*type property*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID264), which is not the same as the instance properties you've created before. That is, you're looking for a way to ask *the `User` type in general* who the currently logged in user is, not ask some specific user. (I'll stop there since this is a learning exercise and you probably want to reach a complete solution on your own...)

Regarding the recursion question: It's totally okay for a type to refer to instances of that type, or for instances of a type to refer to other instances. You could, for example, create a `favoriteTeacher` property on `User` that points to another instance of `User`.

What you do have to watch out for is whether you're creating circular structures (for example, if I say my favorite teacher is [@nate-cook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59541/nate-cook), Nate says his favorite teacher is [@matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt), and Matt says his favorite teacher is me), and whether the algorithm you're writing can safely process a circular structure without getting stuck in infinite recursion or an infinite loop. (If you're planning to find all the favorite teachers by following `favoriteTeacher` properties until you find one that's `nil`, you're gonna have a bad time.)

Comment: Thanks! I've found out what I missed.

Comment: This is still a great Swift starter book. However, a good suggestion is to look around in the book and not rely only on what already has been presented at the point of this exercise. A previous chapter does not contain the necessary info to create a solution that makes sense with the instructions in the exercise in question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right that that would be a recursive structure. The key is that each internal `User` field isn't immediately created, so it doesn't explode in size as soon as a `User` is created.

If an "internal" `User` is created immediately for each `User` created, yes, this would lead to infinite calls to the `User` constructor, and cause a StackOverflow.

Note the wording of the question though:

> Create a currentUser type property on the User struct below and assign it to a user object representing you.

An internal `User` isn't created for each `User` created (which would recurse infinitely if done strictly). One `currentUser` is created, and is given to all the other `User`s. So in this case, no, this does not lead in infinite recursion.

Note, I'm answering from the perspective of someone who doesn't know Swift.

Comment: Thanks! I've found out what I missed.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create currentUser property of type User within the User struct?

There are strict limits on how you'd be able to do that. A struct cannot have an *instance property* typed as the same kind of struct. That would cause memory management issues, and the compiler would stop you from doing it.

Comment: I imagine the book is meant to be referring to a static property. That’s how I would create a `currentUser` property for an example like this I think. It shouldn’t be a property of each instance of User. It should be a static type object on the User type.

Comment: @Fogmeister Probably right.