# I'm stuck on an Exercise in App Development with Swift (Ch. 2.3, Ex. 9). How do I use Type Properties correctly here?

Tags: swift, xcode

1. Imagine you have an app that requires the user to log in. You may have a User struct similar to that shown below. However, in addition to keeping track of specific user information, you might want to have a way of knowing who the current logged in user is. Create a `currentUser` type property on the `User` struct below and assign it to a `user` object representing you. Now you can access the current user through the User struct. Print out the properties of `currentUser`.

   ```
   struct User {
       var userName: String
       var email: String
       var age: Int
       static var currentUser = User(userName: "Bob", email: "bob@gmail.com", age: 18) //This line was typed by me.

       // My answer for the 2nd part.
       mutating func logIn(user: User) {
           currentUser = user
           print("\(userName) has logged in.")
       }
   }
   ```

   print(User.currentUser)
2. There are other properties and actions associated with a `User` struct that might be good candidates for a type property or method. One might be a method for logging in. Go back and create a type method called `logIn(user:)` where `user` is of type `User`. In the body of the method, assign the passed in user to the `currentUser` property, and print out a statement using the user's userName saying that the user has logged in.

Below, call the `logIn(user:)` method and pass in a different `User` instance than what you assigned to currentUser above. Observe the printout in the console.

**EDIT: Figured it out!**

```
struct User {
    var userName: String
    var email: String
    var age: Int
    static var currentUser = User(userName: "Bob", email: "bob@gmail.com", age: 18)

    static func logIn(user: User) {
        currentUser = user
        print("\(currentUser.userName) has logged in.")
    }
}

print(User.currentUser.userName) //Bob
print(User.currentUser.email)    //bob@gmail.com
print(User.currentUser.age)      //18

var newUser = User(userName: "Joey", email: "joey@yahoo.com", age: 20)
User.logIn(user: newUser)     //Joey has logged in.

print(User.currentUser.userName) //Joey
print(User.currentUser.email)    //joey@yahoo.com
print(User.currentUser.age)      //20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran your code, I got the following output " *Bob has logged in.* " your program works. This was my code:

```
   struct User {
    var userName: String
    var email: String
    var age: Int
    static var currentUser = User(userName: "Bob", email: "bob@gmail.com", age: 18) //This line was typed by me.
    // My answer for the 2nd part.
    mutating func logIn(user: User) {
        User.currentUser = user
        print("\(userName) has logged in.")
    }
}
```

What exactly do you want your result to be?

Comment: Btw, you cannot refer to currentUser outside the Struct.

Comment: Most of this code came pre typed for the question. The question is asking me to create a Type Property where I can access the details of the current logged in user. The 2nd question is asking me to create a new User instance, and then use the logIn(user:) method to change the currentUser to a new user with the new user's details. A confirmation message will then come up saying that the new user's name has logged in.

Comment: Someone here also asked the same question, but the Answerer didn't gave a clear answer because he wanted the Asker to figure it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125022/doesnt-creating-a-currentuser-type-property-on-a-user-struct-lead-to-infinite

Comment: Even though you didn't really gave out the full answer, but you did help me realize that "User.currentUser = user" instead of just "currentUser = user" was the code that threw me off. I approved your answer since you're the only one who tried to help. I edited my question to show what I needed to answer the questions.

Comment: Actually, I fixed it again because it wanted me to use a static func instead of a mutating func. That makes "User.currentUser = user" cause an error, but "currentUser = user" right. I'll let you keep the approved answer points or whatever (I'm new to this). I edited my question with the way the book wants me to do it (by using Type Properties and Type Methods).

Answer (score 1):

```
struct User {
    var userName: String
    var email: String
    var age: Int
    
    static var currentUser = User(userName: "Arminius", email: "arminius@me.com", age: 36) 
    //this sets up a 'default' user profile so it isn't blank.
                
    mutating func logIn(userName: String, email: String, age: Int) {
        // this function changes the 'default' user and logs in a new user
        self.userName = userName
        self.email = email
        self.age = age
        print("\(userName) has logged in successfully.")
    }
}
```

You would then call the `logIn(user:)` function by `User.currentUser.logIn()`, logging in a new user. I don't know how our solutions differ but this seems clearer to me that creating a `newUser` then assigning that to the `currentUser`, but then it's been two years and your solution did point me in the right direction.